# Exposed and mapped port in Docker Desktop for mac OS sometimes returns empty reply on host

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

I have Dockerfile looks like this:

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM node

RUN npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-login-form
WORKDIR svelte-login-form
RUN pwd
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

I can build it and run it as a container:

```
$ docker build -t example-for-port-mapping .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.192kB
Step 1/7 : FROM node
 ---> 4ac0e1872789
Step 2/7 : RUN npx degit sveltejs/template svelte-login-form
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c3c9e0ff2612
Step 3/7 : WORKDIR svelte-login-form
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ba9cc2ea671c
Step 4/7 : RUN pwd
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cce7a5f9e8fa
Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 864e37465ec8
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6984ebf0de18
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["npm", "run", "dev"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e4a92c7c1da5
Successfully built e4a92c7c1da5
Successfully tagged example-for-port-mapping:latest

$ docker run --rm -p 5000 -d example-for-port-mapping
7ee5af59b7fd45f8b839520a88fa34fe99992365a78579f19bf2b62924279676

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
7ee5af59b7fd        example-for-port-mapping   "npm run dev"            5 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:32792->5000/tcp   jovial_chatterjee
```

As expected, I can access port 5000 within the container:

```
$ docker exec jovial_chatterjee /bin/bash -c 'curl http://localhost:5000'
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   355  100   355    0     0  14961      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 15434
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width'>

    <title>Svelte app</title>

    <link rel='icon' type='image/png' href='/favicon.png'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/global.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/bundle.css'>

    <script defer src='/bundle.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Because in my example port 5000 is mapped to port 32792, I am expecting the same result by accessing port 32792 locally, yet I get an empty reply:

```
$ curl  http://0.0.0.0:32792
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

**How can I debug this? I am expecting to see the same result on the mapped host port as on the 5000 port on the container.**

This works fine in other cases, for example:

```
$ docker run -dit --name my-apache-app -p 80  httpd:2.4
ba81cbafe62b2409abad9c2a428533aa43b00547f5f192080a4c6c96c2794fea

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                     NAMES
ba81cbafe62b        httpd:2.4                  "httpd-foreground"       4 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:32794->80/tcp     my-apache-app

$ curl 0.0.0.0:32794
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
```

I am using Docker on mac OS 10.15:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.2, build 6a30dfc
```

Thanks!

Comment: A very typical cause is the container process only listening on 127.0.0.1; it needs to listen on 0.0.0.0 to be accessible from outside the container.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I just wanted to post the solution that worked for me. Inside of the project folder you'll find a `README` file.

The `README` file states the following :

> By default, the server will only respond to requests from localhost.
> To allow connections from other computers, edit the `sirv` commands in
> package.json to include the option `--host 0.0.0.0`.

I updated my `package.json` file with the following command :

```
 "start": "sirv public --host 0.0.0.0"
```

I could then access my application from outside of the running container within my web browser.

I hope this helps anyone that might stumble on this question looking for a solution.

Comment: Thanks, this was helping me a lot!! It was enough for me to add --host without 0.0.0.0